# Help w/ Sluggish "rake cucumber"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, cucumber

I've been trying to debug some super slow performance in running my cucumber features.  I've run various calls through ruby-prof and think I see the bottlenecks (not too familiar with using ruby-prof) but do not know the cause or more important the solution.  I've include below the output from running rake cucumber.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1788885/rake_cucumber.txt

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how I could go about debugging it further?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: btw. do you have newest version of cucumber? I heard there were some major performance updates...

Comment: Yes, I have the latest installed.

Comment: Are you running Rails3/Bundler? I see a lot of calls to gem-related stuff in your profile output, but I don't know enough to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what might be making cucumber run slowly for you. As a possible work around, you could considering using [spork](http://github.com/timcharper/spork). On my Windows 7 netbook, running just one cucumber test went from around 7 minutes to 10 seconds with spork.

Comment: I've been starting to test w/ Spork and it seems to work pretty well.  Spork will preload your environment and keep an instance hot.

Answer (score 1):

So, I happen to have been playing around with this all morning.  It turns out that if you do:

```
rake cucumber
```

that does indeed take forever to run.  (About 20 secs on my laptop.)  But, apparently:

```
cucumber
```

runs just fine w/out the overhead of Rake and it runs in about 8 secs.

Comment: I was going suggest that that's the overhead added by rake running cucumber through `bundle exec`, but 12 sec difference is a lot...